# ng2-charts: Datalabels values are not shown in my grapghs

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, deploying

I am working in an angular project with ng2-charts and chart.js. When I run the project locally the datalabels are shown [project run locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJnfR.png). But when I deploy it in a server the datalabels disappear [project run in a server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTfLf.png)

The console does not show any error message.

The libraries versions are
"chart.js": "^2.8.0"
"ng2-charts": "^2.2.3"

Any help, thank you for your support

Comment: import 'chart.js';
import 'chart.piecelabel.js';       Import chart js and chartpiecelabel in order

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import both this js and in this order

```
    // Import chart js and chartpiecelabel in order
   import 'chart.js';
   import 'chart.piecelabel.js';
```

Comment: please add some explanation with your answer, don't just put codes as an answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your advice. At the end I came across with the solution using import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels' in  my-component.ts